# Lazy.nvim - change plugin install location for Windows 10

Tags: neovim, microsoft-windows, lazyvim

Is there a way to change the plugin install location from:

`C:\Users\user1\AppData\Local\nvim-data\lazy`

to let say:

`C:\nvim-data`?

After installing LazyVim, cloning into that folder fails so none of the plugins were installed.

Comment: Do you still have something open in your question? How can we help you further? Otherwise maybe could you accept one of the answers using the v button next to the arrow voting buttons. It allow the question to rest :-)

Comment: let me try your suggestion and I will get back to you.

Comment: Thanks, take your time :-) I'm just interested to make sure we follow up and don't have dangling questions ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can influence the path of the `nvim-data` folder by setting the: `XDG_DATA_HOME` environment variable.

If set, the path of the `nvim-data` folder is `%XDG_DATA_HOME%\nvim-data`

Setting `XDG_DATA_HOME` to `C:\` should do the trick.

Comment: This worked!  Thank you!

Comment: Thanks for the feedback :-) I'm glad your problem is solved ;-)